# Polynomials in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. Suppose $A$ $\in$ $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ and $P$ is and invertible matrix, such that $P \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$.
If $f$ is any polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$, prove that

$$f(P^{-1}AP) = P^{-1}f(A)P.$$

Comment: Have you tried induction on the degree of $f$?

Comment: No, I will think in the solution using induction.

Comment: No need for induction.  Just write out an arbitrary polynomial and use algebraic properties.  See the hint I gave below.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(P^{-1}AP)^m = P^{-1}A^mP$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the proof, let show you, I will be a little bit formal.

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}$[$X$]. Such that $f = \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_ix^i$. For $n,c_i\in \mathbb{F}$.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a linear algebra, and we define $f(\alpha) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i\alpha^i$, for all $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$.

First we will show that $(P^{-1}AP)^m = P^{-1}A^mP.$ This mean the following,

$(P^{-1}AP)^m$ = $(P^{-1}AP)\cdot(P^{-1}AP)\ldots(P^{-1}AP)$ m times.

But as the multiplication of matrices is associative, we get that following:

$(P^{-1}AP)^m = P^{-1}A(PP^{-1})A(PP^{-1})\ldots(PP^{-1})AP$
 $= P^{-1}A^mP$  ----- ($\ast$).

So by the definition of our funtion we get:

$$f(P^{-1}AP) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i(P^{-1}AP)^i$$ by ($\ast$) we can state the following:
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_iP^{-1}A^iP$$
$$=P^{-1}(\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_iA^i)P$$
$$=P^{-1}f(A)P$$ As we wanted to proof. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Good job, this was what I had in mind.